# copy a file in safe and efficient way in thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to copy the contents of tempFile to CacheFile in a thread in safe and 
efficient way.

what is myscript takes 1-2 min times to write to a file (ie. tempFile) and after sucessfull .I need to copy to cacheFile so who ever call the function (getStudentDetails) will get serve from cachefile rather than tempFile to avoid the delay(though first call always will be delay for 1-2 min since cacheFIle will empty).

**Note: I NEED TO USE FILE  NOT PRIMARY STORAGE**

Below is my approach it working fine but can it be more efficient and safe?

```
bool unlock=true;

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex     = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t  condition_var   = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


    void * runScriptAndUpdateCacheFile (  void * arg  )
{

    std::cout<<"Inside thread lock"<<endl;

    unlock=false;  // to avoid multiple call to this thread  till it get complete 
    char tempFile[32]={0};
    strncpy(tempFile,"/tmp/smbXXXXXX",14); // tempFile is the main file where my script will dump the output


    if( mkstemp(tempFile) < 1)
    {
        cout<<"fail to create temp file"<<endl;
        return (NULL);

    }

    if (tempFile != NULL)
    {
        char command[256] = {0};
        sprintf(command, " myscript > %s", tempFile); 
        int status=system(command);  // write ouput of script to tempFile
        if (status < 0)
        {

            std::cout << "Error: " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
            return(NULL);
        }
        else
        {
            if (WIFEXITED(status))  // fetch exit code
               {
                std::cout << "Program returned normally, exit code " << WEXITSTATUS(status) << '\n';
                std::ifstream  src(tempFile, std::ios::binary);
                    std::ofstream  CacheFile((char*)arg, std::ios::binary); 
                                 Cache << src.rdbuf();  // Copy to cacheFile
               }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Program exited abnormaly\n";
                return(NULL);
            }
        }
    }
cout<<" thread is unlock"<<endl;
unlock=true;

}
```

**getStudentDetails can be called multiple times**

```
void getStudentDetails()
{
    pthread_t threads;

        char CacheFile[32]={0};

        strncpy(CacheFile,"/tmp/CacheFile",19);
       //Serve from CacheFile rather than orignal file coz this file
       //will take 1-2 min to dump in it
    std::ifstream fin(CacheFile);

     if(unlock)  // to avoid multiple call to thread when multile call made to getStudentDetails
                  // this unlock is made false when it enter to thread and made true when exit
      {
    pthread_mutex_lock( &count_mutex );
        int rc = pthread_create(&threads, NULL, runSmbtree, CacheFile); // pass cache file to thread  this file will get updated with 
                                    // orignal file create by script.
       pthread_mutex_unlock( &count_mutex );
      }
        std::string line;

        while (getline(fin, line))
        {

            // reading Cachefile and serveing when getStudentDetails called by client
        }
}
```

**Valgrind complains with below error**

1. =3535== HEAP SUMMARY:

   ==3535==     in use at exit: 864 bytes in 3 blocks

   **==3535==   total heap usage: 169 allocs, 166 frees, 78,323 bytes allocated**

   ==3535==

   ==3535== Searching for pointers to 3 not-freed blocks

   ==3535== Checked 25,373,616 byte

   ==3535==

   ==3535== Thread 1:

   ==3535== 864 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1

   ==3535==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)

   ==3535==    by 0x4012E54: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:296)

   ==3535==    by 0x4012E54: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:460)

   ==3535==    by 0x5359DA0: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:589)

   ==3535==    by 0x5359DA0: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:500)

   ==3535==

   ==3535== LEAK SUMMARY:

   ==3535==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

   ==3535==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

   ==3535==      possibly lost: 864 bytes in 3 blocks

   ==3535==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

   ==3535==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks

   ==3535==

   **==3535== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)**

   ==3535==

   ==3535== 2 errors in context 1 of 2:

   ==3535== Thread 2:

   ==3535== Syscall param open(filename) points to unaddressable byte(s)

   ==3535==    at 0x565B4CD: ??? (syscall-template.S:81)

   ==3535==    by 0x55E9E07: _IO_file_open (fileops.c:228)

   ==3535==    by 0x55E9E07: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:333)

   ==3535==    by 0x55DE2E3: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:90)

   ==3535==    by 0x4EB29BF: std::__basic_file::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode, int) (in

   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)

   ==3535==    by 0x4EEAEA9: std::basic_filebuf >::open(char const*, std::_Ios_Openmode) (in

   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)

   ==3535==    by 0x4EEC747: std::basic_ofstream >::basic_ofstream(char const*,

   std::_Ios_Openmode) (in

   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)

   ==3535==    by 0x40200B: runScriptAndUpdateCacheFile(void*) (in ***)

   ==3535==    by 0x5359181: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)

   ==3535==    by 0x566A30C: clone (clone.S:111)

   ==3535==  Address 0xffefffba0 is on thread 1's stack

   ==3535==  384 bytes below stack pointer

   ==3535==

   ==3535== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Comment: Neither of `getStudentDetails()` or `runScriptAndUpdateCacheFile()` directly calls each other, and the implementation of `runSmbtree()` isn't posted so there's no information about how the threads might interact.  That said, how `unlock` is used looks fishy to me.  Also, nothing ever joins the thread which is also suspect..

Comment: please check updated

Comment: My mistake i made the changes please refer the updated question

Comment: The handling of `unlock` is definitely a race condition (undefined behavior) and whatever you're trying to do with `count_mutex` isn't doing anything since it's only being locked/unlocked on one thread (assuming that `getStudentDetails()` isn't called from different threads).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but I don't think threads will help since I no requests can be worked on until the cached file has been created. Putting that creation on a separate thread won't speed things up since everything else would need to wait for it anyway.  But maybe I'm misunderstanding something.  I feel like I'm not getting the whole picture.

Comment: *"it working fine"* - but then you are posting pages of error output? It's entirely not clear, what you are looking for. If everything is working fine, then why post the error output? If it isn't working fine, then instead of asking for a more efficient way to break stuff, you should ask about those issues, and address them. Anyway, do take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @MichaelBurr thanks for suggestion .i too feel i am not able to put it correctly . Well let me explain in short . i have script which takes 2 min time to complete and dump in a file every time when thread called .So what here i planed is to create a another file(cachefile) which will serve client(with old data) and when script complete it update the cachefile..